# JsonObject of JsonObjects in JAVA

Tags: java, json, loops

I have a `JSONObject` full of `JSONobject`s, and I need to extract each of those into a new `JSONObject` so I can manipulate each of them individually, but I don't really know how to do it. My code is like this:

```
public void loadBodies(InputStream in) {

JSONObject jsonInput= new JSONObject(new JSONTokener(in));

JSONObject jo2 = jsonInput.getJSONObject("bodies"); //probably incorrect
for(JSonObject j: jo2) b.create(j); //i need to apply the create method to all the JSONObjects
```

imagine the JSON like this

```
{'bodies': [
        {
            'total': 142250.0, 
            '_id': 'BC'
        }, 
        {
            'total': 210.88999999999996,
             '_id': 'USD'
        }, 

        {
            'total': 1065600.0, 
            '_id': 'TK'
        }
        ]
}
```

I need to extract all the `JSONObject`s under the key `bodies` into a new set of `JSONObjects`, so I can operate with them. So basically, extract them in a loop, but I don't know how to.

Comment: You need to provide example `JSON` payload. From which package `JSONObject` type comes from?

Comment: i don't know if thats what you need, but i am using the org.json I think it is an easy thing, but i dont know how to extract all the json objects individually from my json of jsons

Comment: Thanks, please, also provide example `JSON` and what do you want to achieve. Right now it is not easy to understand.

Comment: it's a Json of Jsons, i don´t have an example... Simply i have under a key, as the value, a series of Jsons i have to "extract" individually.

Comment: basically, i need to parse the JSON and extract all the JSONS that are in the value field in a loop. imagine something like this

Answer (score 0):

According to your example, `bodies` is a JSON array. So use `JSONArray` of the `org.json:json` library in order to iterate over the array's content:

```
String     json      = "{\"bodies\": [{\"total\": 142250.0, \"_id\": \"BC\"}]}";

JSONObject jsonInput = new JSONObject(new JSONTokener(new StringReader(json)));
JSONArray  array     = jsonInput.getJSONArray("bodies");
for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject obj = array.getJSONObject(i);
     // implement here your logic on obj
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this and manipulate each value according to your requirement . This method calls recursively every time when it finds any JSONObject or JSONArray inside object.
handleValue() method for manipulating value for specific key.

```
public void handleJSON(Object input, Map<String,Object> result ){
if (input instanceof JSONObject) {
  List < String > keys = new ArrayList < > (((JSONObject) input).keySet());
  for (String key: keys) {
    if (!(((JSONObject) input).get(key) instanceof JSONArray))
      if (((JSONObject) input).get(key) instanceof JSONObject) {
        handleJSONObject(((JSONObject) input).get(key), map);
      } else {
        Object value = ((JSONObject) input).get(key);
        ((JSONObject) input).put(key, handleValue(value, map));
      }
    else
      handleJSONObject(new JSONArray(((JSONObject) input).get(key).toString()), map);
  }

}
if (input instanceof JSONArray) {
  for (int i = 0; i < ((JSONArray) input).length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonObject = ((JSONArray) input).getJSONObject(i);
    handleJSONObject(jsonObject, map);
  }
}
}
```